# Check PEP8 in data structure

Tags: python, pep8

I am using [**pycodestyle**](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle) for checking code style, but I realized in this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Button:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, text="empty"):
        print foo
        print bar
        print text


# Not valid
button = Button(1, 2,
         text="Player 1")

# Valid
buttons = [Button(6, 7,
           text="Player 2")]
```

In [**PEP8 about indentation**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) says that the ideal would be this:

```
button = Button(foo, bar,
                text="Player 1")
```

Or:

```
button = Button(
         1, 2,
         text="Player 1")
```

However I do not understand why this is valid:

```
buttons = [Button(6, 7,
           text="Player 2")]
```

Is it because of the *data structure* or is it a *pycodestyle* bug?

Comment: Did you check some of [pycodestyle repo issues matching "hanging"](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hanging+is%3Aopen+)? ["Missing lint for inconsistent indentation"](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/667) can be related.

Comment: WOW!! There are many problems, now I believe this tool is not reliable. Even so I will wait to be sure if data structure affects something in PEP8. Thanks!